# Persiting many records in Doctrine causing memory exhaustion

Tags: doctrine-orm

I'm using the Symfony2 Framework with Doctrine using a mysql database, when running a Symfony command on the command line such as ...

```
/path/to/php app/console myCommand
```

This command is to update loads of records (about 35,000+) and I get a memory exhaustion at 1Gb, is there a better and probably more efficient way to run these commands so I dont get this issue?

I could increase the memory limit but ultimately this is going to fail again at some point.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Would be nice for some author feedback.

Comment: been 2 years no answer, whether the ones posted or your actual solution

Comment: I can't remove the -1 without the question being edited

Comment: hmmm thanks, a -1 for no reason, stupid!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using batch processing To handle the updates in chunks.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/batch-processing.html

Answer (score 0):

Call clear on the entity manager

```
$em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
$em->flush();
$em->clear();
```

As you are only updating your data, and not requiring it to remain in memory.